# Data types of able to process in Hyperledger Iroha

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-iroha

While I'm working on Hyperledger Iroha examples, I realised the data which is sending, receiving, storing in the chain is in numeric types like coins.

Was Iroha developed for only like these types of blockchain? For example can I store JSON data which has more than one field in Iroha ledger?

Answer (score 3):

Hyperleder Iroha allows you to send not only assets (you might get such impression due to a highly developed set of commands and queries for serving such assets) but any data that will be stored in the chain as well.

The current implementation provides that opportunity at least via [SetAccountDetail](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/commands.html#set-account-detail) command and [GetAccountDetail](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/queries.html#get-account-detail) query.